# How to explode a list column in python polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a list column in polars dataframe as below.

[image]

I would like to do an explode on this column so that the all list elements will be in a single column as below.

[image]

How to get the list column explode operation done in polars?

Answer (score 4):

DataFrame.explode

https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html

```
import polars as pl

data = {'a': [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

print(df.explode('a'))
```

```
shape: (9, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 1   │
│ 2   │
│ 3   │
│ 4   │
│ 5   │
│ 6   │
│ 7   │
│ 8   │
│ 9   │
└─────┘
```